# Cells not visible on first screen are not tappable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

[image]

I have used a UIScroll View. It has a contentView (of type UIView) which again has a questionView (UIView) and a _questionTableView (UITableView). I know this is not the right practice but the design required me to implement like this. Scroll is working perfectly fine.

I have a total of 8 cells and only 4 cells are visible when the screen is opened first. Upon tapping on any of these 4 cells

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called.

Upon scrolling down, rest of the cells become visible. But tapping on them doesn't trigger **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

I read various stack overflow posts on this issue (to enable tapping on cells) where people suggested to increase the content view size/ scrollView's contentSize/ tableView's height. I tried all of them but no luck.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_questionTableView.frame.size.width, 1000);
_contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _questionTableView.frame.size.width * 2, 1000);
_questionTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _qTableView.frame.size.width , 500);
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
return cell;
}
```

Is there nay way to make the cells tappable?

EDIT: I experimented some more and I realized that after several taps on the cell, the method - **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** is called. But those are some random taps 5-6 times. Couldn't identify a pattern.

Comment: It is better to refactor your code. Using scrollView inside another scroll view is not good idea

Comment: The design does not permit to.

Comment: Possibly you can replace tapToMatchView and questionView by custom table view cell.

Comment: There are 2 tableviews placed adjacent to each other inside the scroll view which I haven't shown. The design doesn't permit me to make the changes. Is there anyway to make the cells tappable?

Comment: @AsthaGupta Actually `UITableview` have scrollView property, so what actually `UITableView` is doing in the `UIScrollView`?? Can you pls explain I am not getting what are you trying to do. I already 2-3 times toyour question.

Comment: Does your tableview is allowed to scroll or not?

Comment: dont allow to scroll tableview

Comment: I want 4 elements to scroll together. one ui view, then another ui view then 2 uitables placed adjacent to each other. hence i implemented a scroll view

Comment: _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.questionTableView.scrollEnabled = self.answerTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
did this already

Comment: so you have two tableviews inside scrollview , so are you checking which tableview's cell is tapped?

Comment: yes. I am. but the call should at least reach the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to check on what table the tap is triggered. That;s not happening.

Comment: check properly all settings of both the tableviews i.e. delegate,datasource,userInteraction

Comment: If there had been a problem like the ones you mentioned then none of the cells should have been tappable. The first 4 are tappable but upon scrolling next 4 ain't tappable

Comment: yes,that's also true..

Comment: I experimented some more and I realized that after several taps on the cell, the method - didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called. But those are some random taps 5-6 times. Couldn't identify a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deselect property **"Delays Content Touches"** in your parent scroll view. It may help!

[image]